# How do I export all of my customers (not users) from Drupal into a CSV file?

Tags: database, importing-exporting

I'm working on integrating a new accounting system and crm (Xero & Capsule) for a client - and they have just under 10,000 clients - only stored in their Drupal website. I need to export these with all their details (e mail, full name, address etc) - into a csv or excel file.

Currently under **Store Administration** I can "*View Customers*" - but this gives me no option to export.

But under **Reports > Customer Reports** it gives me the option to export each page to a csv - however the information is not what we need - it only gives me usernames.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export module you can create views and export to CSV, Excel, XML, etc.

It also supports exporting in batches (default activated if the views has 1 000 or more rows). So 10 000 clients shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Hi Maarten

Thanks so much for the advice. I am now trying to work out how to actually install a module in drupal. In the Site Building menu I am in the module section - but cannot see an option for installing a module ?

Sorry I am totally new to Drupal.

Comment: No problem. I suggest you read a few basic tutorials on Drupal before jumping into a complex task. Start here to learn how to install a module: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/modules-themes/modules-7

Answer (score 1):

Another module to consider for addressing these requirements is [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena).

You would use it's report writing features (such as its WYSIWYG report writer and/or it's query builder) to first create a report that fits your needs (e.g. to remedy your '... the information is not what we need - it only gives me usernames ...'). The result of it could be a tabular output and/or graph. After the report content matches the specifications,you could save it as (e.g.) a CSV file.

Here is a quote from one of the forena community docu pages, i.e. [Reasons for considering Forena](https://www.drupal.org/node/2360187):

> Reports created by Forena (combined with SVGGraph and mPDF) can be
>   saved (exported) as PDF documents with embedded graphs. Other
>   supported formats for saving a report are CSV, XLS, DOC, HTML, etc.

The Forena [Video demos and tutorials](https://www.drupal.org/node/2360187) contain quite some links to live demos.

Any report created with [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) can be saved (exported) in various file formats, such as CSV or XLS. To do so, just add `.csv` as an extention to the report (output) URL. That contains the CSV equivalent of that report. As a sample, consider the sample report located at `/reports/sample.states` (in your own site, one of the samples shipped with Forena). Change the URL to `/reports/sample.states.csv` (= just add `.csv` to it) to get the same report in `.csv` format. If you'd add such `.csv` to the URL of the [Simple Table of States in the demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states), the result is [like so](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.states.csv) ...

Same technique applies for other supported extensions (export formats), such as adding `.html`, `.xls` (MS Excell), `.pdf` or `.doc` (MS Word).

By the way, all *data blocks* are accessible directly via their url also, provided you have permission to access that block. Here are a few samples of that, for the sample report located at `/reports/sample.states`:

- in [XML format](http://forenasolutions.org/forena/xml/sampledb.states) (= demo **with** anonymous access).
- in [JSON format](http://forenasolutions.org/forena/json/sampledb.states) (= demo **with** anonymous access).
- in [XML format](http://drupal.placeto.be/forena/xml/sampledb.states) (= demo **without** anonymous access).
- in [JSON format](http://drupal.placeto.be/forena/json/sampledb.states) (= demo **without** anonymous access).

For short, to answer this specific answer I'd write the various (custom) SQLs I need, format it as reports that fit my needs, and then just save it as an XLS (or CSV?).

Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena).